# Como parar o serviço do SQL Server usando o C#

Tags: c#, sql

Gostaria de saber se é possível parar o SQL Server usando linhas de código do C#.

Tenho uma aplicação em C# e gostaria de adicionar um botão para parar o serviço do SQL ou a instancia, dessa forma consigo trabalhar com os arquivos .mdf e .ldf seja para fazendo bakup ou substituir. Sei que é possível parar manualmente através do gerenciador de serviço do Windows mas quero fazer isso de forma prática.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Acredito que desta forma ele ira executar o `CMD` e rodar o comando que da stop no serviço faça um teste para ver se resolve seu problema.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/c net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

Comment: Testei, porém não deu certo. Ele deveria abrir a janela do 'CMD'? Usei exatamente o código que você me informou alterando apenas o nome da instancia 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESSPOS4'. Devo fazer mais alguma alteração?

Comment: não, ele não ira abrir o CMD por causa dessa linha `startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
` se você quiser que o CMD apareça basta comentar ele. já que não funcionou faça o teste do comando `net stop` com a  sua instancia diretamente no CMD e veja se ira funcionar.

Comment: Fiz direto no CMD e deu "Erro de sistema 5. Acesso negado". Executei o CMD como administrador e deu certo. Porém mesmo executando minha aplicação como administrador e mesmo assim não funciona. Teria alguma forma do meu programa executar o CMD como administrador?

Comment: `process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` tenta adicionar esse comando antes de `.StartInfo = startInfo;`

Comment: Estamos quase chegando lá (risos..). Comentei a linha `startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;` para ver o que ocorria exatamente no CMD. O CMD abre porém o comando não é digitado dentro dele e não é executado, na janela do CMD que abriu eu digitei o código `net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESSPOS4` e funcionou. O que pode ser?

Comment: haha faltou um `/c` nesta linha `startInfo.Arguments = "/c net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS";` adiciona ai e faz um teste.

Comment: Deu certo!!! Muito Obrigado!